# Why can't I static_cast LPWSTR* to LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm reading a book, and it gave an example where a C-style typecast is used to convert a pointer to a LPWSTR buffer `LPWSTR*` type to a `LPWSTR` type. Having just learnt C++, I tried changing it to use static_cast instead, but it gave errors. (Quite honestly I'm not surprised, why is it even okay to typecast a (pointer to a pointer type) into a pointer type?)

Could someone explain why this is so? Here is the code I am looking at:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ShowError <number>\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int message = atoi(argv[1]);
    LPWSTR text;

    DWORD chars = ::FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | // function allocates
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    nullptr, message, 0,
    (LPWSTR)&text, //<<<<<< I try replacing this with static_cast<LPWSTR>(&text)
    0, nullptr);

    if (chars > 0) 
    {
        printf("Message %d: %ws\n", message, text);
        ::LocalFree(text);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("No such error exists\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are using MSVC, the error message also indicated the solution (use `reinterpret_cast` instead). A `static_cast` cannot be used to convert between unrelated types. The type cast works since you're converting between pointers, both of which have the same size and layout on platforms where Windows can run. The code still has a bug: It should call `FormatMessageW`, not `FormatMessage`.

Comment: The cast is not allowed with `static_cast` for good reason and requires `reinterpret_cast` instead. It is generally very dangerous and shouldn't be done. That the function [FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) from the Windows library requires it is in my opinion terrible API design.

Comment: Before converting, you might want to look at the data type of it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/50e9ef83-d6fd-4e22-a34a-2c6b4e3c24f3 There's a difference between * to wchar_t and ** to wchar_t

Comment: As a general tip: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do) in a C++ program, you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In this case it is expected by the library function. See the documentation for the `lpBuffer` parameter in the link I posted.

Comment: The root cause of the problem, I'm guessing, is that the function was coded without the possibility to allocate the buffer. Then when it was added, instead of creating a new function or updating the argument type, they did a very ugly "hack", which requires some very bad casting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *"instead of creating a new function or updating the argument type"* - Neither one is really an option, especially the latter will break the ABI, and all shipped programs using it stop working. *"requires some very bad casting"* - No, not really. This is a C function and you can pass `text` or `&text` without any casts. The casting is required only if you choose to call it from, say, C++.

Comment: @IInspectable How many `...Ex` functions have MS added to its API? :) Yes they are strong proponents of backward-compatibility, which have caused them untold problems in the past, but they are also happy to add new functions that do the same thing but in a new and (supposedly) better way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The `Ex` APIs didn't arrive until 32-bit Windows (Win9x/NT). `FormatMessage` predates that, and if you look up the system requirements for Windows 3.0 you'll quickly understand that compiling a program was constantly hitting those limits. If you didn't have constraints, it would be easy and obvious to come up with a better design. But there were constraints, and they were real, and I'll challenge you to come up with a better solution that doesn't violate those constraints.